# The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured) in wamp server

Tags: mysql

I am currently getting this error in my phpmyadmin:

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

I tried googling and give each solutions i found a try. Unfortunately, nothing worked for me.

By the way, I am using wamp server.

Below is my configuration file of config.inc.php from C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1.

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Comment: It comes to me sometimes and automatically i am getting it cleared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mysql default port is 3306 can you try putting it and then try

Comment: How did you put the default port 3306 ? Can you please put the command ? Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

There are possible solutions here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,64808,254785#msg-254785
and here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,23138,254786#msg-254786

All of these are config settings. In my case I have two computers with everything in XAMPP synced. On the other computer phpMyAdmin did start normally. So the problem in my case seemed to be with the specific computer, not the config files. Stopping firewall didn't help.

Finally, more or less by accident, I bumped into the file:

...path_to_XAMPP\XAMPP...\mysql\bin\mysqld-debug.exe

Doubleclicking that file miraculously gave me back PhpMyAdmin.
Posted here in case anyone might be helped by this too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By double clicking mysql\bin\mysqld-debug.exe it worked. +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 13):

I face the same problem and changing

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issues fresh install and same error surprising. Finally I figured out it was a problem with browser cookies...

1. Try cleaning your browser cookies and see it helps to resolve this issue, before even trying any configuration changes.
2. Try using XAMPP Control panel "Admin" button instead of usual `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`
3. Try direct link: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/main.php` or `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/main.php`
4. Finally try this: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=phpmyadmin&server=1&target=db_structure.php`

Somehow if you have old installation and you upgraded to new version it keeps track of your old settings through cookies.

If this solution helped let me know.

Comment: Vote for you. I had the issue again. My solution doubleclicking mysqld-debug.exe (see my post) didn't help this time. Emptying my cache did.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MAMP, make sure it's started. :)

I just ran into this problem, and after starting MAMP the error went away. Not my finest moment.

Answer (score 1):

I use XAMPP and had the same error.  I used [Paul Gobée](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1872387/paul-gobee) solution above and it worked for me. I navigated to `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld-debug.exe` and upon starting the `.exe` my Windows Firewall popped up asking for permission.  Once I allowed it, it worked fine. I would have commented under his post but I do not have that much rep yet... sry! Just wanted to let everyone know this worked for me as well.