# Error in opening phpmyadmin in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am a Ubuntu User. I had installed XAMPP with:

```
username='root' 
password=''
```

then I've installed mysql-server with:

```
username='root'
password='something'
```

now when I am opening phpmyadmin of xampp I am getting the following error

[image]

please help...!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured) in wamp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178547/the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not-correctl)

Comment: It can also be an issue caused by your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reconfiguring phpmyadimin:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the port no. on XAMPP for MY-SQL. it works for me.