# How can i configure phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I install xampp server in vm and i accessed to it from another machine, for xampp server it work but i have this problem in phpmyadmin when i navigate to https://ip/phpmyadmin:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#2002 – The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server’s socket is not correctly configured)
```

i configure file config.inc.php and i change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; localhost to my adress ip but it always same problem.
How can i fix it? 
I want to have access remote to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured) in wamp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178547/the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not-correctl)

Comment: I would connect by the command line client, then run the `STATUS;` command to see your "Connection" and "Current user". You can then compare those to what's in `config.inc.php`; for instance if your Connection is Localhost via UNIX socket but phpMyAdmin is using connect_type tcp, you might try making phpMyAdmin connect by socket to test.