# WAMP issue in my windows7 system

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have installed wamp after installing fresh OS. I have installed mvscr110.dll files too. Everything went fine for the first time but when i restart my system the wamp will not turn green.It stays yellow. I have tried many options available on stackoverflow but non of them worked. I have even uninstalled and re-installed the program but from the next restart the problem starts again, Apache is running on port 80 but Mysql is not running also phpmyadmin shows error -

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

## Note: The configurations in the file config.inc have also been done properly

I have re-installed the program for 3-4 times but WAMP works until the shutdown. Once restarted problem comes in again. This issue is not fixing. Please some one help out how to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the MySQL error log? Have you looked at the Windows Event Viewer for error messages from MYQSQL?

Comment: Do you install WAMPServer as an Administrator? That is a requriement!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> mysql\bin\mysqld-debug.exe

Remember, MySQL on wamp runs on port 3306

source : [mysql forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,23138,254786#msg-254786)

refer this SO thread for reference : [The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured) in wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178547/the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not-correctl)